# edit and delete button Add in server side data table in php ,ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I put edit a button but how can I pass id of each row. 
Its server side data table but I don't know how get id for edit and button

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                    url :"packing-grid-data.php", // json datasource
                    type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                    error: function(){  // error handling
                        $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                        $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                        $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");
                    },

                },

                "columnDefs": [
                {

                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<a href='view_product.php?id=' name='edit' class='btn   btn-primary'> VIEW </a>",

                    "targets": -1
                    }
                ]

            });
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. You can prepare the Edit and Delete button html in the PHP code and pass it in ajax response
2. Using datatable jquery createdRow callback.Check below code. In the code data[1] means id value from database.

   var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
       "processing": true,
       "serverSide": true,
       "ajax":{
           url :"packing-grid-data.php",
           type: "post",
           error: function(){
               $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
               $("#employee-grid").append('No data found in the server');
               $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");
           },
       },
       "columnDefs": [
       {
           "data": null,
           "targets": -1
       }
       ],
       createdRow : function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
           $( row ).find('td:eq(-1)').html(' VIEW ');
       }
   });

Comment: great. if you need any other help let me know. thanks

Comment: If my answer has solved your issue, vote me or give me your review

Comment: where's the option ??

Comment: Please check my above screenshot and give your favour

Comment: yaa i show that and i do that bt  " You can't vote for your own post "i show that message

Comment: Give vote to my answer. I have given vote to your post

Comment: yaa thank you..but  i show that message  "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Ok, once reputation will increase to more than 15 than give it vote and mark question as correct